# AS3 getting a textField.text on Click Event

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So, I'm back with more problems with my Flash App.

I have a list of several movie clips in sucession, that are "MiniInfos", containing some details about some "works". These are added to the stage in a cycle, and each time I need to add a eventlistener(MouseEvent.CLICK) to be able to click it to show more details. The problem, to know which details should come up next, I need to acess a TextField that contains the ID to be able to pass it to the next Movieclip (lets call it "BigInfo").

So, I know it sounds confusing, but ill try to summarize.

There are several MiniInfos added to the stage with TextFields like "ID: 1, ID: 2, ID: 3", etc.

I want to be able to click one and another movieclip (BigInfo) gets added to the stage with more details about it. To know which info I should pull up on the PHP, I need to know the ID from which MiniInfo I clicked.

My ideia (which didn't work) was:

```
//on the cycle
MiniInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OpenWorkDetails);

//further down the code
public function OpenWorkDetails(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
        trace(MiniInfo.IDTrabalhoField.text);
        //If I figure this number out, I will change it to addChild
        }
```

So, I get an error 1120: Access of undefined property MiniInfo.

I realize this code isnt exactly the best, so If you guys got a diferent solution in mind, feel free to share. Im still learning flash.

Thank you.

Marco Fox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a small flash application to demonstrate a different approach you can take:

**FLASH**

Main.as(document class):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;

    [SWF(width="275", height="175")]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _phpPath:String = "http://localhost/stackoverflow/minibiginfos/getBigInfo.php";
        private var _bigInfo:BigInfo;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {   
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var xml:XML = <miniInfos>
                              <miniInfo id="1" text="Mini Info 1" />
                              <miniInfo id="2" text="Mini Info 2" />
                              <miniInfo id="3" text="Mini Info 3" />
                          </miniInfos>;

            for (var i:uint = 0; i < xml.children().length(); i++)
            {
                var miniInfo:MiniInfo = new MiniInfo(xml.miniInfo[i].@id, 
                                                     xml.miniInfo[i].@text);

                miniInfo.x = 25;
                miniInfo.y = 25 + ((miniInfo.height + 25) * i);
                addChild(miniInfo);

                miniInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMiniInfoClick);

            }// end for

        }// end function

        private function onMiniInfoClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            loadBigInfo(MiniInfo(e.currentTarget).id);

        }// end function

        private function loadBigInfo(id:int):void
        {
            if (!_bigInfo)
            {
                _bigInfo = new BigInfo();
                _bigInfo.x = 150;
                _bigInfo.y = 25;
                addChild(_bigInfo);

            }// end if

            var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            urlVariables.miniInfoID = id;

            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(_phpPath);
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            urlRequest.data = urlVariables;

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(urlRequest);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoaderComplete);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

        }// end function

        private function onURLLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
        {
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.currentTarget);

            var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(urlLoader.data);

            _bigInfo.text = urlVariables.text;


        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;

internal class MiniInfo extends Sprite
{
    private var _id:int;
    private var _text:String
    private var _width:Number = 100;
    private var _height:Number = 25;

    override public function get width():Number { return _width } 
    override public function get height():Number { return _height }
    public function get id():int { return _id } 
    public function get text():String { return _text } 

    public function MiniInfo(id:int, text:String):void
    {
        _id = id;
        _text = text;

        graphics.beginFill(0xE1E1E1);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
        graphics.endFill();

        var textField:TextField = new TextField();
        textField.x = textField.y = 5;
        textField.text = text;
        textField.mouseEnabled = false;
        addChild(textField);

    }// end function

}// end class

internal class BigInfo extends Sprite
{
    private var _width:Number = 100;
    private var _height:Number = 125;
    private var _textField:TextField;

    public function get text():String { return _textField.text } 
    public function set text(text:String):void { _textField.text = text; } 

    public function BigInfo()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0xE1E1E1);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
        graphics.endFill();

        _textField = new TextField();
        _textField.width = 90;
        _textField.wordWrap = true;
        _textField.x = _textField.y = 5;
        _textField.mouseEnabled = false;
        addChild(_textField);

    }// end function

}// end class
```

**PHP**

getBigInfo.php:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $bigInfos = array
                    (
                        array
                        (
                            'miniInfoID' => 1,
                            'text' => "This is the big info for mini info 1"
                        ),
                        array
                        (
                            'miniInfoID' => 2,
                            'text' => "This is the big info for mini info 2"
                        ),
                        array
                        (
                            'miniInfoID' => 3,
                            'text' => "This is the big info for mini info 3"
                        )
                    );

        $text;

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($bigInfos); $i++)
        {
            foreach($bigInfos as $item)
            {
                if($item['miniInfoID'] == (int)$_POST['miniInfoID'])
                {
                    $text = $item['text'];
                    break;
                }

            }// end foreach

            break;

        }// end for

        print "text=$text";

    }// end if

?>
```

The following is an image of the flash application running:

[image: minibiginfos flash application]

Answer (score 1):

```
public function OpenWorkDetails(e:MouseEvent):void{        
    trace((e.currentTarget as MiniInfo).IDTrabalhoField.text);
}
```

Comment: Error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property IDTrabalhoField through a reference with static type MiniInfo.

Do I need to import something?

Comment: @Marco Fox - what is miniinfo? how IDTrabalhoField is declared there?

Comment: IDTrabalhoField is a dynamic text field (properly named IDTrabalhoField, I know it works because I used it before) inside a MovieClip named MiniInfo. this miniInfo is added to stage via addChild inside a while cycle. All of this is inside a "Container" MovieClip.

I know its confusing, so ill chart it better:

MainSWF.swf>Container.as>MiniInfo(MovieClip)

Comment: @Marco Fox - my example works only if `MiniInfo` is a custom class with a public textfield `IDTrabalhoField`. Else (if you know the depth of IDTrabalhoField inside of MiniInfo) use `trace(((e.currentTarget as MovieClip).getChildAt(IDTrabalhoField_depth) as TextField).text);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure MainFInfo, your MainINfo.addEventListener and OpenWOrkDetails are all in the same MovieClip?

The error you are getting means that MainInfo does not exist in the same MovieClip.
lee

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that MiniInfo is not declared in scope.  If it is a class instance, then it would work, but if MiniInfo is declared inside of a function it will be "forgotten" as soon as you exit that function.  That is why you have to do what www0z0k did, and use the currentTarget property of the event.

Comment: MiniInfo doesent have a AS file, If I do one for it, will it start working?